# When does WP ignore content added through the backend editor?

Tags: homepage

In the same way that content added through the editor of a 'blog home' page (main page of posts) is ignored, are there other pages/instances where content added through the backend editor is ignored?

To elaborate further, the following is stated in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page):

> **DO NOT add content**. Leave it blank. Any content here will be ignored -- only the Title is used.

Does the same rule apply to any other pages/instances in WordPress?

Comment: What do you mean by "ignored"? Please explain your question.

Comment: @ fayazmiraz...  Codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page): 'DO NOT add content. Leave it blank. Any content here will be ignored -- only the Title is used.'

Comment: To my knowledge, in a stock WordPress installation, that will only happen on the **Blog** page of a site using a static front page. Plugins and themes may also choose to ignore the content of a given page, but that's not standard WordPress behaviour.

Comment: @gulliver OK, based on your comment I've edited your original question & answered it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It entirely depends on the theme you are using on your site. The default theme will only ignore the `content` of the `blog` home page. The reason is:

> By default, the `blog` home page (or when the latest posts is selected as `front page`) only lists the posts as archives.

[image: WordPress Static Front Page Setting]

However, this behaviour is changeable from the theme. For example, you may customize `home.php` theme file to change the look & feel of that page or show `content` added from the backend `editor` along with recent blog listings. As stated in the [WordPress Document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page):

> Do not use a custom Page template for this page. The template files `home.php` or `index.php` will be used to generate this page in the Theme.

So as you see, it entirely depends on the theme you are going to use. It's no way a core WordPress feature & WordPress by itself will neither **ignore** any content added from the backend `editor`, nor will it show
them. Depending on your **active** `theme` and `plugins`, they'll be shown or ignored.

However, as you've stated, **default WordPress themes** generally ignore the page `content` added from the backend editor from the blog home page. This is the only place it does so & the behaviour is modifiable from themes and plugins, even when you are using any of the default WordPress themes.

Also note that, contents such as `category description`, `post excerpt` etc. may also be ignored, however, as it is already stated above, all of these completely depend on the theme you are using (& sometime even the plugins).

You may follow [this WordPress document](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/) to understand how the theme template files behave & modify your theme behaviour accordingly.

Comment: @ fayazmiraz ...thanks for the clarification. In my custom themes I use a modified home.php, containing hard-coded text to preface the blog posts. I recently discovered a modification (http://webdesignfromscratch.com/wordpress/wordpress-tip-1-page-content-on-the-posts-page/) to allow such text to be instead added through the editor.